# How to use code splitting on a ressouce (.json, .csv, etc.) with React

Tags: json, reactjs, react-intl

### Issue:

I am using **react-intl** and I would like to load the language-related **JSON file** only when it is needed, in brief to **lazy load it**.

### Documentation :

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html
the problem here is I wish to lazy load a JSON file not a component, so I am a bit lost about how to use it without JSX.

### Actual code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {IntlProvider} from 'react-intl';
import English from "../i18n/en.json";
import Polish from "../i18n/pl.json";

const local = navigator.language;
let lang;
switch (local){
    case "pl":
    case "pl-pl":
        lang = Polish;
        break;
    default:
        lang = English;
}

function Wrapper () {
[...]
}

export default Wrapper
```

### What I try which **did not** works :

test 1:

```
import React from 'react';
import {IntlProvider} from 'react-intl';
const English = React.lazy(() => import('../i18n/en.json'));
const Polish = React.lazy(() => import('../i18n/pl.json'));

const local = navigator.language;
let lang;
switch (local){
    case "pl":
    case "pl-pl":
        lang = Polish;
        break;
    default:
        lang = English;
}

function Wrapper () {
[...]
}

export default Wrapper
```

test 2:

```
import React from 'react';
import {IntlProvider} from 'react-intl';
const English = React.lazy(() => import('../i18n/en.json'));
const Polish = React.lazy(() => import('../i18n/pl.json'));

const local = navigator.language;
let lang;
switch (local){
    case "pl":
    case "pl-pl":
        Polish.then(polish => {lang = polish});
        break;
    default:
        English.then(english=> {lang = english});
}

function Wrapper () {
[...]
}

export default Wrapper
```

test 3 (inspired from [How to import Json file with React lazy loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59106159/how-to-import-json-file-with-react-lazy-loading)) :

```
import React from 'react';
import {IntlProvider} from 'react-intl';

const local = navigator.language;
let lang;
switch (local){
    case "pl":
    case "pl-pl":
        import("../i18n/pl.json").then(Polish=> {
            lang = Polish);
        });
        break;
    default:
        import("../i18n/en.json").then(English=> {
            lang = English);
        });
}

function Wrapper () {
[...]
}

export default Wrapper
```

In case more code is needed (the function Wrapper for example), please let me know in a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same issue where I wanted to code split my JSON in React. I found a work around that uses the dynamic import function.

I wasn't using Intl so I can't confirm this works for your needs but this is what worked for my needs (and I think it should work for you)

I created a function to return a promise with my data that I needed to code split. I then called this in my Component in an Async func with an await on the data.

My use case was to fetch data from an API, if that was done, load a cached JSON of the data.

```
const loadCached = (key) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    import(`../datasets/cached/${key}.json`).then((data) => {
      res(data?.default);
    });
  });
};
```

I then called it from my `async catch`

```
const cachedData = await loadCached(key);
```

So for you use I would keep my `loadCached` function (maybe rename it to like `loadLang`)

then wrap it in a `useEffect` to fire on load to change the language and gather the JSON.

Here is how I would approach your issue (untested code)

```
const local = navigator.language; // get language
const [lang, setLang] = useState("English"); // for a default of english

// fire when we get local from DOM
useEffect(() => {
  async function getLangData() {
    const response = await loadLang(local);
    setLang(reponse);
  }
getLangData();
}, [local])


const setLang = (lang) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    import(`../i18n/${lang}.json`).then((data) => {
      res(data?.default);
    });
  });
};
```